# Possible bug in dalvik of Android 2.x during Bitmap allocation?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, native, out-of-memory

**The phenomenon**: First do allocation some big memory blocks in the Java side until we catche OutOfMemoryError, then **free them all**. Now, weird things happen: load even a small picture(e.g. width:200, height:200) by BitmapFactory.decodeXXX(decodeResource, decodeFile, ...) will throw an OutOfMemoryError! But its OK to alloc any pure Java big Object(e.g. new byte[2*1024*1024]) now!

**Verifying**: I wrote some simple codes to verify the problem that can download [here](http://cs.lcsky.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/OOFProblemVerifier.zip), press "Alloc" button many times and you will got an OOF Error, then press "Free All", now the environment is set up. Now you can press "LoadBitmap" and you will see its not work on most of Android 2.x phone.(But in the emulator its just OK, odd)

**Digging deeper**: I try to dig into some dalvik code to find out why, and find a possible bug in function externalAllocPossible in [HeapSource.c](http://droid292.googlecode.com/svn-history/r103/trunk/dalvik/vm/alloc/HeapSource.c) which called by dvmTrackExternalAllocation who print the "xxx-byte external allocation too large for this process" messages in LogCat.

In externalAllocPossible it simply wrote:

```
if (currentHeapSize + hs->externalBytesAllocated + n <=
            heap->absoluteMaxSize)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Which means once if the native Bitmap allocation size plus the currentHeapSize(**NOT the actually allocated size** as shown below, in this case, it's keeping the max size of the heap we bumped up but then freed them all) exceeds the limits, **native Bitmap allocation will always fail**, but the currentHeapSize in Java seems **NOT** decrease even when 91.3% Java objects' memory have been freed(set to null and trigger GC)!

[image]

Is there anybody else met this problem too?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct.  Its forcing the entire app (Java+native) take no more than a certain amount of memory from the OS.  To do this it has to use the current heap size, because that amount of memory is still allocated to the app (it is not returned to the OS when freed by GC, only returned to the application's memory pool).

At any rate, 2.x is long dead so they're not going to fix it there.  They did change how bitmaps store their memory in 3.x and 4.x.  Your best bet is to allocate all the bitmaps you use first, then allocate those large structures.  Or better yet-  throw those large structures into a fixed size LRUCache, and don't use the grow until out of memory idea, instead load new data only when needed.

Comment: I think you are right, in this way they guaranteed memory used in  (Java+native) would not exceed the limitation. But with this behavior of the Android 2.x, we the developer's long list of memory usage tips added another one: allocate all the bitmaps first before other large structures or using some equivalent methods :(

Answer (score 0):

The class *Bitmap* has the [*recycle()*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) method, described as:

*Free the native object associated with this bitmap...*

The reason behind this method is that there are two heaps: the Java heap and the heap used by native code. The GC only sees the Java heap sizes; for GC, a bitmap may look as a small object because it's size on the Java heap is small, despite the fact that it references a large memory block in the native heap.